# Obtaining a subset from the data frame cutting off the outliers

Tags: r, quantile

I am working with a dataset ([csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TwfoLzl-dGhSirmmZhb6EJSFw2PLsHAi/view?usp=sharing)) on the 195 countries' inflation rates for the 1980-2020 period. I'd like to produce chart that describes the distribution of the inflation values across the 1980-2020 period. In the meantime I have produced this chart:

[image]

My problem with the chart is that I would like to depict a truncated dataset: with inflation values that are in the 99.5% percentile and the outliers being eliminated from the dataset. Any insight is very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain better the steps you need? For example: 
1. Exclude 0.25% of each tail (keep 99.5%), then
2. Exclude the outliers, meaning the outliers of each box plot (Interquartile range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `quantile`-function:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  filter(value <= quantile(value, 0.995))
```

removes every value > 99.5 % percentile calculated per year. If you don't want it to be calculated per year, remove the `group_by()`-line.

Comment: Thanks very much! This solves my question.

Comment: As Fernando Barbose noted, you should consider also removing the lower 0.05 %.

Comment: Thanks for reminder! I did it this way:
`r <- .005;
imf.inflation_trcd <- imf.inflation %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  filter(value <= quantile(value, c(r, 1-r)))` 
The resulting chart is attached [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14pHXzy51gCFfsNHPT3T72o9bBAdWCPR3/view?usp=sharing)